# ruby read csv but on two different rows simultaneously

Tags: ruby, multithreading, file, pointers, csv

Let's say, I can read CSV by the built in CSV parser. like this:

```
CSV.foreach(file_path, quote_char: '"', col_sep: ',', row_sep: :auto, headers: true) { |line|
    #some code here
}
```

this code reads and parse whole csv from start to end.

So, my question is if it is possible or some no-lame way to read the CSV simultaneously > like one part of script would read csv from start to half and second part of script from half to end just by accesing the file on disk?

! without reading the csv into array/memory/other

ruby pseudo code (with knowing all lines in file)

```
threads = []

threads << Thread.new do
    csvread(startrowindex,halfrowindex)
    end

threads << Thread.new do
   csvread(halfrowindex+1,endrowindex)
   end
threads.each(&:join)
```

Comment: No, CSV reads the file sequentially. What you could do is read CSV and distribute lines lazily to several different worker threads as they arrive.

Comment: hmm, that is actually a very good idea, thank you, i will try that!

Comment: hmm, i must be doing something wrong... it is slower than before!!! :D :( help please

Comment: See the comment at the end of my answer. You cannot speed up anything using threads in MRI except blocked IO, since MRI runs only one thread at a time. If you are after speedups, either go with JRuby or Rubinius, or use processes instead of threads.

Answer (score 2):

What I said in the comments - for example, using the [`peach`](http://peach.rubyforge.org/) gem:

```
require 'csv'
require 'peach'

CSV.foreach("a.csv").peach(2) do |row|
  row.map(&:to_i).reduce(&:+)
end
```

If you are using MRI, you will suffer from GIL; if the workers are doing some heavy lifting, this code should be a bit slower than the non-threaded one. If your slowness is related to CPU, switch to JRuby or Rubinius, as they don't have GIL. If it is related to IO blocking, then this should help even on MRI.

Comment: well, i tried that, but probably the file is just too big, or i have a small amount of ram (8GB) so no success. I will probably go by with my old slow but reliable solution. Anyway, big thanks for your ideas and help!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean - why does RAM matter? The file should be loaded one row at a time. What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: I am getting no error. When I open the task manager in windows, i just see only that ruby had consumed all free ram and nothing is happening. my csv file has about 3.8mil rows and about 2.5GB

Comment: Okay, I found the issue - my deepest apologies, it seems that `parallel` doesn't work with iterators properly (it coerces the collection `to_a` unless it is a lambda, which made it load the whole CSV into memory). Changing to `peach` should solve that issue.

Comment: do not worry :) so i will have to have require parallel and peach and then, in code Parallel.peach(CSV.foreach(...)) ?

Comment: ah, you changed the code, okay, thank you, i will try that also

Comment: No, just `peach`. There are a bunch of different libraries for threaded master-worker pattern (peach, parallel, workers, parallel-each, producer-consumer...), they all do more or less the same thing. I already changed the sample code in the answer to work with `peach` instead of `parallel`. (Forgot to change the link, fixed that too)